# Read specific Word(Line 2, Word 3) from a text file by batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I need to read specific words from a text file through batch script. Say I want Line 2 word 3 to be read.

Here is the code::

```
   @ECHO OFF
    cls
    SET /P line=Please enter Line number: 
    ECHO Line number entered is : %line%

    SET /P word=Please enter Word number: 
    ECHO Word number entered is : %word%


    FOR /F "tokens=%word% skip=%line% delims=," %%G IN (E_dir.txt) DO echo Chosen word is: %%G
```

The problem is, this gives me all the 3rd words starting from line 2. (say, user input is line 1, Word 3). There is a problem with the line count, But I can handle that. My problem is it is giving me all the words when I need only the single word of Line 2 and word 3.

Input file: `E_Dir.txt`

```
January,Snowy,02
February,Rainy,15
March,Sunny,25
April,Test,20
```

Output:

```
Please enter Line number: 1
Line number entered is : 1
Please enter Word number: 3
Word number entered is : 3
Chosen word is: 15
Chosen word is: 25
Chosen word is: 20
```

Expected Output:

```
Please enter Line number: 1
Line number entered is : 1
Please enter Word number: 3
Word number entered is : 3
Chosen word is: 15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way the first
...

```
FOR /F "tokens=%word% skip=%line% delims=," %%G IN (E_dir.txt) DO echo Chosen word is: %%G&goto nextline
:nextline
```

Way the second
...

```
set showme=Y
FOR /F "tokens=%word% skip=%line% delims=," %%G IN (E_dir.txt) DO if defined showme set showme=&echo Chosen word is: %%G
```

---

Amendment

```
SET /a showme=line-1
SET showme=skip=%showme%
IF %line% equ 1 set "showme= "
FOR /F "tokens=%word% %showme% delims=," %%G IN (E_dir.txt) DO if defined showme set showme=&echo Chosen word is: %%G
```

Note that where `%line%` is 1, `showme` is deliberately set to a SPACE. This ensures that `showme` has a value initially.

I have no idea where your stray "2" is coming from. The procedure worked for me. Perhaps you may want to check the sourcefile with a hex editor. It may have a line without a LF. Possibly also check your batch. If you've used NOTEPAD, try an editor like EDITPLUS or NOTEPAD++. Notepad does some strange things.

Comment: Nice Sir..!!! Works.. I am so foolish.. didn't know how to use `'&'`. Thanks a ton..

Comment: I am getting an extra number printed at the last..   Please enter Line number: 1
Line number entered is : 1
Please enter Word number: 3
Word number entered is : 3
15
2

Comment: From where is this `'2'` is coming at the last..?