# Searching and executing from a specific line in a file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, batch-processing

I've a file PublicHolidays.txt, below are the contents (one html script in a line). Windows 7

```
A.html
B.html
C.html
D.html
```

If the user inputs B.html (Ignoring case) then my batch file should start executing from B.html till end of file i.e. D.html

I refereed this article but it doesn't seems to [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830130/read-specific-wordline-2-word-3-from-a-text-file-by-batch-script)

Overview: I need to write a batch job that executes either all the contents specified in a txt file or take user input and execute the command from that line (basically 1st search that string in a file and the start executing from that line).

```
@echo OFF
Echo **********************************************************************
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion    
 SET TOTAL=0
 FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%I IN (PublicHolidays.txt) do (
SET LN=%%I
FOR %%J IN ("!LN!") do (
    FOR /F %%K IN ('ECHO %%J ^| FIND /I /C ".html"') DO (
        @SET /A TOTAL=!TOTAL!+%%K
    )
)
 )

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

ECHO *************Total !TOTAL! *************
Echo.

SET /p ScriptName=Please enter the Script Name :
IF [%ScriptName%] EQU [] GOTO ScriptName

for /f "tokens=%ScriptName% skip=%line% delims=," %%j in (PublicHolidays.txt) do (
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CALL specificCmd -s -i %ScriptName% >> outout.txt
 )
Pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /p ScriptName=Please enter the Script Name :

for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%j in (q26519180.txt) do (
 IF /i "%scriptname%"=="%%j" SET "scriptname=" 
 IF NOT DEFINED scriptname ECHO(call specificCmd -s -i %%j.%%k
 )
GOTO :EOF
```

This should work for you.

I used a file named `q26519180.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(call` to `call` to actually execute the process with the files.

Note also that I've removed the redirection to make my testing easier.

Comment: Thanks @Magoo but its works partially. If a delimiter is specified then it fails i.e If the content of the file(PublicHoliday.txt) is 
     A
     B
     C
     D
Then it works.

Comment: I just modified to 
IF /i "%scriptname%"=="%%j.%%k" SET "scriptname="
its working fine.... cheers!