# how to write batch script on command prompt to extract nth line from multiple txt files?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

What's the batch script I should write on Windows command prompt to extract the values from 20th line of 200 text files and put them into a new text file named "master.txt"

Each text files contains hundreds of lines, and I only need the value from line 20.

For example

text file name:

test1.edit.txt

test2.edit.txt

test3.edit.txt

......

Sample File:

Line 1 - xxxxx

Line 2 - xxxxx ......

Line 20- PROPERTY 100

Result:

PROPERTY 100 (from test1.edit.txt)

PROPERTY 200 (from test2.edit.txt)

PROPERTY 300 (from test3.edit.txt) ......

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try this: `for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %a in ('findstr /N /R "." *.txt ^| findstr /R "\<37:"') do echo %b>>master.txt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read specific Word(Line 2, Word 3) from a text file by batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830130/read-specific-wordline-2-word-3-from-a-text-file-by-batch-script) If not, you can find several other examples by searching this site for `[batch-file] read specific line from file`.

Comment: I'd offer: `(For /F "Tokens=2,* Delims=:" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /NP "^" "*.txt" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LI ".txt:20:"') Do @Echo(%H) 1>"master.txt"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copy this code to a batch file. Drag the folder where the TXT files are to the batch file. It should save all "line 20" text to a file called "Result.txt"

```
@echo off

if /i exist "%~1" (if /i not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)

set "Folder=%~1"
if /i exist "Result.txt" del /q "Result.txt"

pushd "%Folder%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do Call :GetLine "%%a"

popd
cmd.exe /c start "" notepad Result.txt
exit

:GetLine
for /f "skip=19 eol= delims=" %%a in ('type "%~1"') do (
                                                        echo %%a
                                                        >>%~dp0Result.txt echo %%a
                                                        goto :EOF
                                                       )
goto :EOF
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need Notepad to be involved at all. You can echo the content directly into the file from the batch file without any manual intervention. If you're going to do it your way, there's no need to write a batch file at all - you could just use Windows Explorer. The purpose of doing it with a batch file is so you **don't** have to do it by hand.

Comment: Draging and doping is easier than writing the path in a variable especially if you have several different folders with text files or if they frequently change. Notepad is only used to open the result.txt so the user don't have to click on it after the job is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cigwin installed, write a,simple bash script
that looks like:

```
for f in `ls f?`; do
   head -9 $f | tail -1
done
```

change the "f?" to find whatever your file names are (mine
are f1, f2, f3).  Save the script as "line9" and run it as
**bash line9**

If you don't have cygwin, consider installing it. :-)
It really does have lots of useful unixish tools.

Comment: Why would they need to install something, especially a package containing many other things, when their system will very likely already have PowerShell? With that, they could use `GC`, (Get-Content), and `Select`, (Select-Object), with `-First 20` and pipe that to `Select` with `-Last 1`.